# Google Maps API Marker Drop onScroll

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am currently trying to trigger my `google.maps.Animation.DROP` when scrolled to certain part of the page. I am getting success triggering the markers to drop on the map; however, the same markers will drop on the same location multiple times. Is there a way for the markers to drop just once when the map is visible?

Here is my current code:

```
var cities = [
  //tokyo
  {lat: 35.6895, lng: 139.6917},
  //fukoka
  {lat: 33.5904, lng: 130.4017},
  //bangkok
  {lat: 13.7563, lng: 100.5018},
  //seoul
  {lat: 37.5665, lng: 126.9780},
  //taipei
  {lat: 25.0330, lng: 121.5654},
  //hong kong 
  {lat: 22.3964, lng: 114.1095}, 
  //shanghai
  {lat: 31.2304, lng: 121.4737}, 
  //xiamen
  {lat: 24.4798, lng: 118.0894},
  //macau 
  {lat: 22.1987, lng: 113.5439}, 
  //phnom penh
  {lat: 11.5449, lng: 104.8922}, 
  //vientiane
  {lat: 17.9757, lng: 102.6331}, 
  //chiang mai
  {lat: 18.7061, lng: 98.9817},
  //kyoto
  {lat: 35.0116, lng: 135.7680}, 
  //osaka
  {lat: 34.6937, lng: 135.5022}, 
  //guam
  {lat: 13.4443, lng: 144.7937}, 
  //san francisco 
  {lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194}, 
  //las vegas 
  {lat: 36.1699, lng: -115.1398}, 
  //los angeles
  {lat: 34.0522, lng: -118.2437}, 
  //paris
  {lat: 48.8566, lng: 2.3522},
  //brussels
  {lat: 50.8503, lng: 4.3517},
  //amsterdam
  {lat: 52.3702, lng: 4.8952}   
];

var markers = [];
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 25.0330, lng: 121.5654}
  });
}

function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(cities[i], i * 200);
  }
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
  }, timeout);
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#map').offset().top,
       hH = $('#map').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && (hT > wS) && (wS+wH > hT+hH)) {
       drop(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: What about setting a variable once your markers were dropped so they don't get dropped again?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've tried setting a Boolean `var dropped = false` and set `dropped = true` at the end of the drop function but had no luck....

Comment: Sorry to say this, but your code seems very poor.  why everytime you are removing and adding markers when windows scrolls ?   What exactly you are trying to achive ?

Answer (score 0):

just don't call the drop function if there are already markers in your map

```
if(markers.length == 0) {
   drop();
}
```